# i2c problem on LPC2148

Tags: arm, i2c, pullup, lpc

I have problem with getting my LPC2148 to work with i2c devices. LPC is on 3.3v bus and i2c devices are on 5v bus with pull-up of 3k6 ohm on either 3.3v or 5v (jumper selection).
What im experiencing is that measuring SCL with oscilloscope i see that frequency of the square signal is ok (5us high and 5us lower).

The problem is that low is not really low. High level is 3.0v and Low is 2.2v. Well of course communication is not working ...

[image: i2c level]

Schematic is quite simple. uC is connected to i2c devices with Rp on pin2 of "jumper selection" High. pin 1 is 5v and pin3 is 3.3v. No matter what i do with jumper i get the same signal output. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Impossible to say, with what you have provided. It might be your software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check you pull up resistor value. It is really 3k6 or 3R6 by mistake.
- Is the Pin of your MCU configured properly ( alternate function, no internal pull-ups enabled ?)
- Is there a short to Vcc somewhere on the board ?
- Are the MCU pin 5V complient ?
- Are you using internal i2c module of the mcu? because open drain pins are necessary here.

Comment: It is SMD 362 (3600 ohm). I did select pin mode for i2c, it is internal module. MCU pin is 5v compatible. As far as the short to VCC, hard to say. Other parts of board is working. (ADC, uart0,1)

Comment: Ok, then disable i2c mode and set the pins to output low manually. Is the driver able to pull the lines to 0V ?

Comment: Ok, disabled i2c and set the output to low and line is 2.2v. On other pins, when i set 0, line goes to 0v.

Comment: It means that the line it tied somewhere else to 3.3V. If it's a proto, I would disconnect every other part of the bus and see it the line can go to 0V. I have the feeling that it is a short somewhere. Probably a defect on the PCB or a very small solder bridge. Inspect the traces carefully using a magnifying equipment.

Comment: Hrm, for some reason i2c chn0 cant drop line to 0v but i2c chn1 is ok. When setting Hight it goes to 3.3v and when setting low it goes to 0v. I havent tried protocol itself cause on PCB peripherals are connected to i2c0...

Comment: Channel1 is working, protocol is implemented and everything is ok. It seems that there is malfunction on i2c chn0.